# how to change possition of laravel app.blade.php brand image

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am working with Laravel 5.2 and I have a branding image in my `app.blade.php` file, as follows:

```
<!-- Branding Image -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
    <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/levis.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" height="50" width="50">                                            
</a>
```

but now I need to change the position of my branding image with same div. then how can I do this?

Comment: Move it *how*? Left ten pixels? To the footer? You'll either have to change/move the HTML or apply some CSS positioning.

Comment: I have applied style to this but it is not working

Comment: Show us **what** style rules you attempted, and tell us what *specifically* you're looking to change - where do you want it to move to? How far? What should it look like at the end?

Comment: need to move image right hand side

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=boostrap+navbar+brand+right+side

Comment: depends on the size of your navbar brand but this should work:  add `left: 90%; postion: absolute;` to `.navbar-brand` class.